# Is "wtf" an abbreviation or a euphemism?

Tags: slang, terminology

In the English language we have a lot of euphemisms for profanities that take the form of abbreviations; for instance, people may say *the f-word* or *the s-word* if they don't want to say *fuck* and *shit*. I always used to assume that *WTF* was the same type of thing.

However, I've noticed lately that if people are reading out loud a sentence that contains *wtf*, they often pronounce it as *what the fuck* - for instance, if they get a text message saying "Hey, wtf just happened?" and another person asks them what the text says, they are likely to say *what the fuck just happened?* instead of *double you tee eff just happened*? In this usage, *wtf* isn't a euphemism; it's just an alternate way of writing the profane phrase so that it is easier to type, i.e., an abbreviation.

So, my question: Which do we consider it? (And has it always been that way? For instance, perhaps it started out as a euphemism but is evolving into an abbreviation?)

Comment: How do those same people read _omg_? It may simply be that the _w_ in _wtf_ causes people to use the option with fewer syllables.

Comment: that's a good question. I've heard some (though) fewer people read it as "oh my god" instead of "oh em gee", which would indicate that (at least for such people) this is a productive phenomenon and not just the fault of the "w".

Comment: I actually consider it to be an acronym.

Comment: @DKrueger Personally, I pronounce it "ohmgeu".

Comment: @Beth: An acronym is some initials that are pronounced as a word, like NASA. Also, the answer would be much better if say why you think this.

Comment: Very good point. What's the point of me stating my point of view if I do not state my reasons. Thank you. 

Not all acronyms are pronounced as a word. MIT is not pronounced like "mitt", but it's still an acronym. To me, acronyms are a subset of abbreviations, comprised (usually) of the first initials of a title (or phrase).

Comment: MIT would only be an acronym if pronounced as a word, like "mitt". But it's usually pronounced as letters, like "M. I. T.", so it's not an acronym. In both cases it's an abbreviation. Acronyms are a subset of abbreviations; they're the abbreviations that are pronounced as words.

Comment: Funny, in the six years since then **people now do say dubya tee eff** - heh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If people actually pronounced WTF "*dubya tee eff*," it would be an [*initialism*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/initialism) (an abbreviation pronounced by spelling out the letters one by one).

In the acronym-mad military, WTF actually is said "*dubya tee eff*" and functions as a euphemism (apparently in those rare cases where decorum needs to be observed).

In practice, people use it as an *[abbreviation](http://www.wordnik.com/words/abbreviation)* that means, "where I write *WTF*, say *what the f^ck*."

Comment: To be truly precise, an acronym should be pronounceable, like "MIDI" not just spelled out, like "MP3".  pronouceability is what makes an initialism and acronym.

Comment: You are correct; I actually have a [previous answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49815/correct-capitalization-for-of-in-an-acronym-definition/49831#49831) to that effect. However, I'm referring to the _military_ as being "acronym-mad;" WTF remains an initialism, as my first paragraph states.

Comment: In the military, we say "Whiskey Tango Foxtrot !? (over)

Answer (score 5):

I would say it's just an abbreviation. The fact that people normally speak the words out in full should be seen as evidence for that.

A *euphemism* is an alternative for a vulgar/profane form, intended to avoid giving offense to hearers / readers / God. I can't see how that would apply to a written form which is basically just intended to save typing.

Answer (score 0):

Euphemism  is a relation to the function of a term, not the term itself.  If I say "Oh Fudge!"  I may be deferring the pain of a burned finger in the presence of a toddler, or expressing delight at the appearance of a chocolate treat.  Only the former use is a euphemism.