# Making acronyms/initialisms from hyphenated words

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms, initialisms

Should we use only the first part of a hyphenated compound word to coin an initialism/acronym?

E.g. would "on-site detector circuit" become OSDC or ODC?

Or does it depend on the particular hyphenated word?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of posts on this site related to acronyms/initialisms, but I couldn't see one that *directly* addressed your question. However, a bit of sleuthing came up with the following.

First, note that OSDC and ODC are **initialisms**, as the capitals are not pronounced as a single word but instead are pronounced individually - see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204086/is-iou-an-abbreviation-an-acronym-or-an-initialism).

Regarding hyphens, [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49815/correct-capitalization-for-of-in-an-acronym-definition/49831#49831) quotes from the Chicago Manual of Style (CMS), and while the quotation doesn't explicitly refer to hyphens, it includes the following example:

> [transmission-control protocol/Internet protocol (TCP/IP)]

**Based on that example, it can be assumed that the CMS would render your "on-site detector circuit" as *OSDC.***

Comment: But the word "control" may be specifically important to include to reduce ambiguity, whereas the word "site" offers little to no extra value. I suppose it's a start though ☺.

Comment: Yes, good point. And while consistency in style is important, I think the primary consideration must be to avoid confusion, so it really comes down to a judgement on whether including the "S" helps *the target audience* to quickly grasp what the term means. You are probably in the best position to judge that.