# When creating an initialism of a country's full name, should the "o" in "of" be capitalized once initialized?

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations, proper-nouns, initialisms

When creating an initialism of a country's full name, should the "o" in "of" be capitalized once initialized? For example, should Republic of Ireland be "**ROI**" or "**RoI**"?

Comment: USSR - Union of Soviet Socialist Republic. (I think here 'o' was in lower case. Same could be in these examples too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct capitalization for "of" in an acronym definition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49815/correct-capitalization-for-of-in-an-acronym-definition)

Comment: Will - it's a matter of style. There is no single rule. Consult an appropriate style guide. [This duplicate question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49815/correct-capitalization-for-of-in-an-acronym-definition) shows the Chicago Manual of Style approach.

Comment: We don't see any 'O' in 'USSR', Ram Pillai, either upper or lower case.